# Build linuxcnc on fedora 37

Tags: linux, fedora, cnc

I am trying to build linuxcnc on fedora iot 37 aarch64 following [this](https://linuxcnc.org/docs/html/code/building-linuxcnc.html) link
I installed dependencies using rpm-ostree

```
rpm-ostree install autoconf \
  automake \
  gcc \
  gcc-c++ \
  tcl-devel \
  python-Yapps2 \
  python3-devel \
  python3-tkinter \
  python3-argcomplete \
  libtirpc-devel \
  libudev-devel \
  libmodbus-devel \
  libusb1-devel \
  glib2-devel \
  gtk3-devel \
  intltool \
  boost-devel \
  readline-devel \
  mesa-libGLU-devel \
  libXmu-devel \
  asciidoc
```

I am able to configure and `make` using this command

```
./configure --with-realtime=uspace --enable-non-distributable=yes && make
```

After build I don't see any build file ie linuxcnc to start build application.

Note: To remove `--enable-non-distributable=yes` from configure command I need to install `libreadline-gplv2-dev` which is debian based package alternative of this in fedora is `readline-devel` which already installed but no success.

What am I missing ?

Comment: There are no errors? The return status of make is 0?

Comment: yes no error with make command

Comment: What's in ../bin?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have files in ../bin filder. But still don't know who to start linuxcnc because i don't have linuxcnc command/file in bin folder. and this link I am following is asking me to run linuxcnc command.
All I have are 'linuxcnc_module_helper, linuxcnclcd, linuxcncrsh, linuxcncsvr and linuxcnctop' and other files in bin